# Before watching "Tokyo Ghoul:re" anime, is it necessary to read the manga to understand the story?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I've seen the first episode of *Tokyo Ghoul:re* and I didn't understand anything.

Before watching the anime, is it necessary to read the manga to understand the story?

Comment: you can watch it without reading the manga, you can also watch it without watching the first season, but I wouldn't recommend it. Also, whatever you do, don't watch it and plan on reading the manga as well.

Comment: I saw Tokyo Ghoul and a few episodes of Re. The manga (Tokyo Ghoul: Re) handles the story much better than the anime imo. I'd suggest reading the manga over the anime.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have seen the previous two seasons (anime) - Yes, you can watch *Tokyo Ghoul:re* without reading the manga.

It's fine if you didn't understand the first episode. Things will gradually be explained in the anime, though not in much depth as in the manga, but you will start understanding the story. Just hang on to it for a while...

If you can't wait that long and insist on knowing the back story (which will probably be explained in the anime later), then go on and read the spoilers below.

---

**The ending of Season 2**

> There was a battle between Kaneki and Arima in the end of Season 2. Kaneki was seriously wounded (Arima pierced his brain through the back of the skull, destroyed his left eye and then finished the fight with the stab through the other eye).

**The story of Haise Sasaki**

> Kaneki survives and becomes a prisoner at Cochlea (3rd floor), but becomes amnesiac (experiences total or sometimes partial loss of memories). Arima started bringing him books in the prison and his health improved substantially. Since he lost his memories, Arima gave him a new name using his (formerly Ken Kaneki)'s two favorite kanji from the words "coffee" and "world" - Haise (**Haise Sasaki** as the one in the anime currently being aired).

**The Quinx Squad**

> The CCG then decides for Haise (formerly Ken Kaneki) to be the mentor and overseer of the **Quinx squad** under the supervision of Arima. The Quinx members are referred to as humans with built-in quinque in their bodies, drawing a distinction between them and normal one-eyed ghouls. The members are regarded as human research subjects who have undergone the surgical procedure developed by Dr. Kouitsu Chigyou.

---

And there you have it, the current Quinx squad (Kuki Urie, Saiko Yonebayashi, Tooru Mutsuki and Ginshi Shirazu) under the mentorship of Haise Sasaki as seen in episode 1 of season 3.

Answer (score -1):

In fact it isn't necessary to read the manga or understand the fist season to see the second one. But I can't tell you that you will enjoy the anime as much as if you understand it.