# In which volume of Tokyo Ghoul does the anime's season 2 end?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I finished watching *Tokyo Ghoul √A* and saw the first episode of *Tokyo Ghoul: re*, but I was not able to understand how Kaneki suddenly became Haise. I want to read the manga volume between where season 2 ends and season 3 starts to understand properly.

In which volume of Tokyo Ghoul does the anime's season 2 end?

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between the Tokyo Ghoul anime and manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21249/2516), [Why did Tokyo Ghoul √A completely deviate from the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18391/2516), [Before watching “Tokyo Ghoul:re” anime, is it necessary to read the manga to understand the story?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/46374/2516), [At which chapter does the Tokyo Ghoul anime deviate from the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/57109/2516)

Comment: Hi Aki, I saw these questions but I wanted to find out the exact volume in which this happened to understand what happened in full depth.

Answer (score 1):

Tokyo Ghoul √A isn't canon, meaning the story doesn't follow the manga. Tokyo Ghoul Season 1 ends somewhere in the middle of volume 7, so to be able to follow Tokyo Ghoul: re, you'd have to finish the remaining volumes(7-14).